# Vue with Laravel, passing null props

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Is it possible to pass a null prop? I have defined a master component which takes `user` prop.

```
<div id="app">
    <master :user="{{ $user }}"></master>
</div>
```

Prop is defined like this:

```
props   : {
    user: {
        type: Object
    }
},
```

Now inside the controller I am passing user variable if user is authenticated, otherwise I am passing null:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::check() ? Auth::user() : null;
    return view('master', compact('user'));
}
```

I am getting an issue that `The value for a v-bind expression cannot be empty`. I couldn't make it even if I remove the colon so that it doesn't bind. I also tried explicitly setting that prop is not required, but none of that worked.

Can this be resolved somehow so that I pass a null/empty object to Vue?

Comment: Try setting required property for props to false. That should work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JS null is actually of type object. But the `prop` check of Vue does not consider null to be an object, see [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1961).

Anyway, if `$user` is null, `{{ $user }}` is converted to nothing so you end up with

```
<master :user=""></master>
```

Which is an empty string.

You could either not specify the type, like this:

```
props   : ['user'],
```

or if you want to, specify the type as string or Object:

```
props   : {
    user: {
        type: [Object, String]
    }
},
```

or you create an empty object if `$user` is null:

```
<master :user="{{ $user ?? '{}' }}"></master>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer gives a solution, I think the exact requirement can be easily achieved by using [PHP Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm) and [VUE Multiple Prop Types](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation)

For example:

VUE component prop updated to accept both `Object` and `null` type

```
props: {
    user: {
        type: [Object, null]
    }
},
```

Then in the blade file

```
<div id="app">
    <master :user="{{ Auth::user() ?? 'null' }}"></master>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use null as default value. I usually do this.

```
props: {
    user: {
        type: Object,
        default: null,
    }
},
```

The downside is, when user is changed from null to object, you can't change it back to null.

What I do when I need the clear the object, I use empty object and make it as default.

```
props: {
    user: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => {},
    }
},
```

Comment: Does this work with `<master :user=""></master>`, or will it throw an error because '' is not of type object?

Comment: @Adam yes it will throw error if you put empty string there.